# how to do i change the value of data from server side?

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am trying to set a value from server side in this code. i have a textbox to enter ticket number and when the ticket is validated and activated, i want the used property of this particulare ticket to be changed to true.

i have this code :

```
        TicketBLL Tickets = new TicketBLL();
        ClientDeviceBLL Devices = new ClientDeviceBLL();


        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTicket.Text))
        {
            CVUsed.Visible = false;
            CVUsed.Enabled = false;
            CVMember.Enabled = false;
            CVMember.Visible = false;
            CVInValid.Enabled = false;
            CVInValid.Visible = false;
            lblMessages.Text = MessageFormatter.GetFormattedErrorMessage("You can login using a Ticket Number.");
            txtTicket.Focus();
        }
        else
        {
            Ticket = Tickets.GetTicketByTicketNumber(txtTicket.Text);
            ////// we must enter the value of the correct SN and the Client ID              
            Device = Devices.GetClientDeviceBySN(txtSN.Text , Convert.ToInt32(txtClientID.Text));

            if (Ticket != null)
            {
                //Correct Ticket number
                CVInValid.Visible = false;
                CVInValid.Enabled = false;

                if (Ticket.Used == true)
                {
                    //ticket was used, internet forbidden
                    CVUsed.Visible = true;
                    CVUsed.Enabled = true;
                    CVMember.Enabled = false;
                    CVMember.Visible = false;
                    CVUsed.IsValid = false;
                }
                else
                {
                    //if exists but not used, Ticket accepted
                    //check if device is a member if client divices
                    if (Device != null)
                    {
                        //internet access garanteed
                        CVUsed.Visible = false;
                        CVUsed.Enabled = false;
                        CVMember.Enabled = false;
                        CVMember.Visible = false;
                        CVUsed.IsValid = true;
                        CVMember.IsValid = true;

                       //here is my error.
                       //ticket.used is not changing in the database so the next
                       //time he enters the same ticket number it would go through  
                       //again.

                        Ticket.Used = true;                            
                        Response.Redirect("http://www.google.com");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //device not member, internet access forbidden
                        CVMember.Enabled = true;
                        CVMember.Visible = true;
                        CVUsed.Visible = false;
                        CVUsed.Enabled = false;
                        CVUsed.IsValid = true;
                        CVMember.IsValid = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Ticket Number is not valid
                CVUsed.Visible = false;
                CVUsed.Enabled = false;
                CVMember.Enabled = false;
                CVMember.Visible = false;
                CVInValid.Enabled = true;
                CVInValid.Visible = true;
                CVInValid.IsValid = false;                   
            }
        }
```

how can i automatically update the ticket.used value in the database?!

Comment: Where is your database call to update ticket info?

Comment: Is your question "how do I insert a value into a database?"

Comment: You can't automatically do it. You must manually do it.

Comment: +1 for the nested if's

Comment: Mike, unless I miss understand, you don't know where to start with this? So, I suggest you look at [SQL guide](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp) and the [SQLAdapter class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldataadapter.aspx) as well as the [SqlClient namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Data.SqlClient.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Without making a connection to database you cannot update the value of ticket.used. If you want to know how to connect to database and update, use stored procedures of direct queries to do your work. Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11116882/how-to-update-table-data-in-sql-database).